# Microsoft graph returning bad request when creating event in daylight savings time

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-calendar

I am trying to create an event using Microsoft Graph API. I am getting the following error.

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": "TimeZoneNotSupportedException",
    "message": "A valid TimeZone value must be specified. The following TimeZone value is not supported: 'Eastern Daylight Time'.",
    "innerError": {
      "date": "<Date>",
      "request-id": "<RequestID GUID>"
    }
  }
}
```

How to handle daylight savings time in Microsoft Graph?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's handled automatically. Use `Eastern Standard Time` instead.

Comment: Hi @Jason, Can you provide me the link where it is mentioned that its handled?